# Why does yield return in a property getter break WPF bindings?

Tags: c#, wpf, yield-return

I have a property that performs a yield return in its get function:

Data:

```
public class TestSummary
{
   [Description("Test1")]
   public TestResult Test1 {get; set;}

   [Description("Test2")]
   public TestResult Test2 {get; set;}
}
public enum TestResult
{
   Failed,
   Passed
}
```

ViewModel:

```
private TestSummary TestResults
{
  get { return new TestSummary() { Test1=Failed, Test2=Passed }; }
}
public int TimePassed
{
   get
   {
       return 2;
   }
}

public IEnumerable<String> FailedTests
{
   get
   {
      PropertyDescriptorCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(TestResults);
     foreach (PropertyInfo failedResult in typeof(TestSummary).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                              .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TestResult)).Where(t => (TestResult)t.GetValue(TestResults) == TestResult.Failed))
     {
        yield return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[failedResult.Name].Attributes[typeof(DescriptionAttribute)]).Description;
     }
   }
}
```

XAML:

```
<UserControl>
<UserControl.DataContext>
   <local:ViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
   <StackPanel>
       <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FailedTests}"/>
       <ProgressBar Value="{Binding TimePassed}"/>
   </StackPanel>
</UserControl>
```

Works and compiles just fine (the property is of type IEnumerable). You can even bind to it, and the UI updates correctly. However, having this code breaks other (seemingly random) bindings on other controls, even bindings internal to other user controls.

My question is, why? This is perfectly valid C# and if anything it should break the bound UI control, not others.

**Update**
Updated source code to be more complete. When I used the above, the getter for "TimePassed" was never called and the progress bar's Value was always 0.

If it helps, using the same yield return in a function, calling it and assigning the result.ToList() to the property doesn't break anything. I am still curious as to why the posted code is causing the "TimePassed" binding to fail (getter is never called).

Also interesting is that if I use Snoop to investigate the binding, the getter DOES get called when I try to look at the "broken" element.

Comment: Please post a minimum reproducible example of this behavior.

Comment: Code updated to include enough for me to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Include detailed explanation what "breaks other bindings" mean. I.e. what you do, what is expected, what is happening.

Comment: The getter for the "broken" binding is never called, neither is the convert function if you put a converter on it, and thus the UI never updates. I would expect all bindings to function as if the "breaking" binding didn't exist.

Comment: Do you think that you have posted *a minimum reproducible example of this behavior*? How can anyone attempt to debug your problem without you showing us [*all the relevant code required to reproduce your problem*](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I'm sorry @Sheridan, I have added the code that I forgot (specifically the data objects). Please let me know if you notice something else I missed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all works. Here is my test code.

```
<Window x:Class="BindingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:bindingTest="clr-namespace:BindingTest"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <bindingTest:ViewModel/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel>
            <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding FailedTests}"/>
            <ProgressBar Value="{Binding TimePassed,Mode=OneWay}"/>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</Window>

using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;

namespace BindingTest
{
    public class TestSummary
    {
        [Description("Test1")]
        public TestResult Test1 { get; set; }

        [Description("Test2")]
        public TestResult Test2 { get; set; }

        [Description("Test3")]
        public TestResult Test3 { get; set; }
    }
    public enum TestResult
    {
        Failed,
        Passed
    }

    public class ViewModel
    {
        private TestSummary TestResults
        {
            get { return new TestSummary()
            {
                Test1 = TestResult.Failed, 
                Test2 = TestResult.Passed,
                Test3 = TestResult.Failed
            }; }
        }

        public int TimePassed
        {
            get
            {
                return 2;
            }
        }

        public IEnumerable<String> FailedTests
        {
            get
            {
                PropertyDescriptorCollection attributes = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(TestResults);
                foreach (PropertyInfo failedResult in typeof(TestSummary).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public)
                                                         .Where(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(TestResult))
                                                         .Where(t => (TestResult)t.GetValue(TestResults,null) == TestResult.Failed))
                {
                    yield return ((DescriptionAttribute)attributes[failedResult.Name].Attributes[typeof(DescriptionAttribute)]).Description;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I would look through this and tweak your values to match and see if that helps. If it doesn't then the problem is outside of the scope of the code you posted.

Comment: Thanks for this, this issue seems to be very inconsistent (much more consistent with more bindings in the actual code) and could very well be machine-dependent. I think it is a conflict somewhere in the WPF source. Thanks again!

Comment: What I would look into is changing it from an IEnumerable to an actual list or an array. If it's bound multiple times then each binding will reset the enumerator and give you abnormal results.

Comment: It isn't bound multiple times, but that is what I ended up having to do. Thanks for the help and advice!